# Can I meaningfully apply KNN on output of NN(mapping to Euclidean space)?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, knn

I want to map data to a euclidean space using NN.
On the Euclidean space, I wanted to apply KNN, finding data that is close to each other in the output space.
I am conjecturing, as NN is considerably smooth function, if I apply KNN, the data that is similar to each other will highly likely be picked as neighbor, instead of other distinct data but close to them.
Does my idea make sense that KNN on result of NN will be kind of useless?
Is there any other idea doing the same thing here but can create a more meaningful KNN or find similar data?